# runOnUiThread doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-runonuithread

I see Here3 and Here4 True True on logcat but commands(alertdialog, mediaPlayerStop and VibrateStop) doesn't work in run() method. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

```
    if(check == 1)
    {
        Log.i("XXX", "Here3");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Log.i("XXX", "Here4 " + voiceSwitch.isChecked() + " " + vibrateSwitch.isChecked());
                        if(voiceSwitch.isChecked())
                        {
                            mediaPlayerStop();
                        }
                        if(vibrateSwitch.isChecked())
                        {
                            vibrateStop();
                        }
                        builder.show().dismiss();
                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use run thread with UI 
use `AsynckTask` class and implement the method onPostExecute() with `builder.show().dismiss();`

Comment: I tried it but  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }
}, 3000);

use it like this

Comment: It worked for voice and vibration but builder.show().dismiss(); or cancel doesn't work to close dialog window. Any suggestion?

Comment: for the dialog you should to make sure that you use the context properly

Answer (score -1):

Might be a simple omission like I can see the line

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
```

Has no closing **)**

Guess it should be:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable());
```

Comment: It's the beginning of a larger block `new Runnable() {...}`